# css not loading property using express .ejs nodejs

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

Good evening everyone,

I would appreciate any help.

I got these two routes:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){

        res.render('index');
});

app.get('/registration/add', function(req,res){

        res.render('clientRegistration');
});
```

and this is part of the server:

```
app.use( express.static(path.join( __dirname, './client/static/')));
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded());
app.set( "views", path.join(__dirname, "./client/views/"));
app.set( "view engine", 'ejs');
```

Directory is:

```
MyApp/
    client/
        static/
            registration.css
            styles.css
        views/
            index.ejs
            clientRegistration.ejs
```

On my index.ejs, I have: 
    link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" which loads the .css file perfectly. But when I click the link:
    a href="/registration/add"> on index.ejs, 
it takes me to the clientRegistration.ejs page but the registration.css does not load even though I have:
    link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="registration.css"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe missing `/`  is a problem

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/registration.css">
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. I have the href="styles.css" working perfectly without the "/" , but the href="registration.css" was not working without it.

Comment: In first situation it worked because you were on `/` route but in second situation it searched file in` /registration/add/registration.css` route instead of `/registration.css`. This happens when you forgot to add slash before `href`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a forward slash before your `style.css` href. As it seems to me, everything is setup correctly and it might be only a problem with the current folder reference.